# I can't open IDLE3 on osx11.1

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, homebrew

I've installed python 3.9.1 by homebrew.

```
benlai@laihongbindeAir ~ % idle3
macOS 11 or later required !
zsh: abort      idle3
```

So... I don't know how to fix it.

Help
Or maybe there's something similar that I can use?
report: https://app.box.com/s/u1wm8wf3iqqtr6tebrbofo07pbx0ydta

Comment: You should inform and ask the homebrew people.  IDLE is a python app.  Can you open python with `% python3.9`?  If so, what does `python3.9 -m idlelib` do?  Note: I have no issue running python 3.9.1 and 3.10.0a3 and IDLE on Mohave with the universal2 installer, compiled on 11, on python.org.

Comment: This is not an IDLE issue.  Homebrew links with the the very old (by over a decade and buggy tcl/tl 8.5.9 supplied by Apple.  8.5.9 is even worse with macOS 11.  The fixes are to use the python.org installer, which includes tcl/tk 8.6.10, or wait for homebrew to do the same.  See https://bugs.python.org/issue42691 and https://bugs.python.org/issue42480 for discussions.

Answer (score 0):

If you install 3.9.1 directly from python.org, which is the first release of python to support Mac OS X Big Sur, it will install with its own and newer version of tcl/tk (v8.6) and will install a working IDLE at the same time. IDLE will also become visible in Spotlight Search, putting an end to having to fire up Terminal every time :-)